# Execute batch file(in turn executes exe) from powershell

Tags: powershell, activemq-classic

I am trying to execute a install activeMq service from powershell, for which I am trying to call a batch file (which inturn calls the wrapper.exe) using:

```
& "C:\apache-activemq-5.6.0\bin\win64\InstallService.bat"
```

I am getting `'"wrapper.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,or batch file'`

But when I execute `InstallService.bat` from command prompt I am able to run the service

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Anandh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
& "cmd.exe /c C:\apache-activemq-5.6.0\bin\win64\InstallService.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a relative path to call "wrapper.exe" within the batch script. If this is the case, replace it with the full path to the executable.